# set up different roles for a user in group versus specific project

Tags: gitlab, role

In gitlab, I have a team member who has the general role of developer. I'd need to make him a maintainer for a specific project. I've looked through the documentation but I'm not finding a strait forward answer on how to upgrade his role in the specific project.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have to remove the member from `group` and add him/her to individual projects with a role(`maintainer` for "Specific project" and `developer` for other projects in your case).

Thats the temporary solution I found

Answer (score 0):

Experiment that worked for me:

To have your user in a group with the general role in all group projects, except some specific project where you want to grant him "maintainer" - just open the "Project member" page and invite the same member picking "maintainer" in the "Select a role" dropdown.

The user now is a direct member for this specific project, though continues to have general developer group role for the other projects.